# Python: Count word frequencies and put them into multiple dictionaries

Tags: python

I'm new to python, now I have a txt file like this:

```
Doc 1
aaa bbb ccc ddd ...

Doc 2
eee fff ggg hhh ...

Doc 3
aaa ggg iii kkk ...

...

Doc 11
eee ttt uuu zzz ...
```

Basically what I want to do is to count term frequency for each document and put them into 11 different dictionaries (like "For Doc1, {'aaa':10, 'bbb':5 ...}", build Term - Document matrix at the end. My current code is like following:

```
# split te text file into 11 documents(paragraphs) 
f = open('filename.txt', 'r')
data = f.read()
docs = data.split("\n\n")

# creat 11 tf dictionaries
dictstr = 'tf'
dictlist = [dictstr + str(i) for i in range(10)]

for i in range(10):
    for line in docs[i]:
        tokens = line.split()
        for term in tokens:
            term = term.lower()
            term = term.replace(',', '')
            term = term.replace('"', '')
            term = term.replace('.', '')
            term = term.replace('/', '')
            term = term.replace('(', '')
            term = term.replace(')', '')

            if not term in dict['tfi']:
                dict['tfi'][term] = 1

            else:
                dict['tfi'][term] += 1
```

There are some problems in the last "if - else" step, I'm stuck here. Can anyone tell me how to deal with it? (Don't want to use other packages like "panda") Thank you!
[The txt resource's here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1A_z3vQCbU0AKWIfTI-QbLaWColHurk_LgRDb44x3XnY/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: The input you gave doesn't seem to have any of the characters that you are replacing. Could you give an actual sample of the input text? Although I can guess at what needs to be changed overall, it's hard to tell for sure without seeing the actual input.

Comment: Hi Delirious I've added the input source.

Comment: That link is asking me to request access but I haven't heard anything back yet since clicking the button. Could you use something like https://bpaste.net/ ?

Comment: Sure! Here it is.https://bpaste.net/show/f7b108fe0f7f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code reads in the file you provided, removes the unwanted characters in one pass (VS creating a new string for each use of `.replace`) and saves the word counts in a dict called `result`. The keys are the doc nums (`'XXX9'` -> `'tf9'`) and the values are `collections.Counter` objects with the word counts.

```
>>> import re
... from collections import Counter
... 
... with open('filename.txt', 'r') as f:
...     data = f.read().lower()
... 
... clean_data = re.sub(r'[,"./()]', '', data)
... 
... result = {}
... for line in clean_data.splitlines():
...     if not line:
...         continue  # skip blank lines
...     elif line.startswith('xxx'):
...         doc_num = 'tf{}'.format(line[3:])
...     else:
...         result[doc_num] = Counter(line.split())
... 
>>> list(result.keys())
['tf7', 'tf10', 'tf5', 'tf2', 'tf9', 'tf4', 'tf11', 'tf3', 'tf6', 'tf8', 'tf1']

>>> for k, v in list(result['tf1'].items())[:15]:
...     print("'{}': {}".format(k, v))
... 
'class': 1
'then': 1
'emerge': 1
'industry': 1
'common': 1
'ourselves': 2
'models': 1
'short': 1
'mgi': 1
'it': 1
'actionable': 1
'time': 1
'why': 1
'theory': 1
'equip': 2
```

Let me know if any changes need to be made to help answer your question!

Comment: Thank you so much! It helps a lot! I'll take a careful look to see if there are any further questions.

Comment: Hi, I'm working on how to build TD matrix now! Could you explain the code here: ".format(line[3:])", why it can get the result "tf1 - tf11"? Thank you!

Comment: Sure. The `elif` statement above is looking for a line that starts with `xxx` (since everything has been lowercased). In the file you provided, the lines start with `XXX1` or `XXX2` etc. The part you are referring to is grabbing a slice of the current line (something like `xxx7`) that skips the first three characters (`xxx7` -> `7`). Since the indexes of a string start at `0`, the fourth character of the string is at index `3`. The reason for the colon in `line[3:]`, is to also account for a case like `xxx11` it will take a slice starting from index 3 to the end of the line, `11`.

Comment: Wow thanks!! What if I wanna build a matrix with rows representing terms in each document and columns representing the 11 documents? I have a thought to use "numpy", how to do that based on your code?

Comment: @WWH98932 Using a [pandas dataframe](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#dataframe) might be an option for you. Here is an example of loading the data into one with the rows as the document terms and the columns as the document names. https://bpaste.net/show/4007a48c411f

Comment: Got it. Such a simple way! Thank you!